# HTML form is not validated when I run the url in eclipse browser its not working

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I have to do a form of validation before submitting the call. The below code works fine when I run the URL in the chrome. But when I execute the same in eclipse as `"Run on server"`, the form is not validated. It is taking me to the localhost page. Can you please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance!

```js
function emptyvalidation(field, errorMessage) {
    if (field.value == null || field.value == "") {
        alert(errorMessage);
  field.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


function validateAndSend() {
if (emptyvalidation(nameField,"Please enter your Name")==false) {nameField.focus(); return false;}
    document.getElementById("am_submit").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id = "amf" >
    <div id = "amTitle" > Enter your form header here </div>  
  <form onsubmit = "return validateAndSend()" method = "post" target = "_self" name = "amform" id = "amform" action ="http://localhost:8080/api/postForm" autocomplete = "off" >
      <div style="margin:6px">
            <label style="display:inline-block;width:150px;vertical-align:top">Name:</label>
         <input type="text" class="inputBox" id="nameField" name="nameField" value="">
        </div>
        <div style="margin:6px"></div>
     <div class = "ambutton" > 
            <input type = "submit" class = "am_submit" id = "am_submit" value = "Subscribe" > 
        </div>  
  </form>   
</div> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is it showing any error? and `action ="http://localhost:8080/api/postForm"` why you are using this.

Comment: try to see if there are any error logged in your javascript console.

Comment: @MehrajKhan - That is my rest api call.

Comment: @MrakVladar - If the remove the field.focus(), it works fine. But if i add that, it is not working

Comment: @Kutty instead of `field.focus();` try like this `$("#inputBox").focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing **return** in the form tag, and return a status code in your callback function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function emptyvalidation(field, errorMessage) {
    if (field.value == null || field.value == "") {
        alert(errorMessage);
      field.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


function validateAndSend() {
    if (emptyvalidation(nameField,"Please enter your Name")==false) {
        nameField.focus(); 
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("amform").action = document.getElementById("amform").getAttribute("data-action");
        document.getElementById("am_submit").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div id = "amf" >
        <div id = "amTitle" > Enter your form header here </div>  
        <form onsubmit = "return validateAndSend()" method = "post" target = "_self" name = "amform" id = "amform" data-action ="http://localhost:8080/api/postForm" autocomplete = "off" >
            <div style="margin:6px">
                <label style="display:inline-block;width:150px;vertical-align:top">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="inputBox" id="nameField" name="nameField" value="">
            </div>
            <div style="margin:6px"></div>
            <div class = "ambutton" >
                <input type = "submit" class = "am_submit" id = "am_submit" value = "Subscribe" >
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
</html>
```

I have just removed the action URL and inserting it when form gets validated.